# Interface reference

Tags: c#

I have a doubt, i've searched a lot about it and i haven't found nothing that can explain.

I can have a property referencing an interface inside my class, and make use of DI to fill these property. For example:

```
public interface ITest {
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Test {
    ITest _test;

    public Test(Itest _test)
    {
        this._test = test;
    }
}
```

The problem is, if I have an generic interface, and my class don't make use of generics, when i create these property a compile error is raised

```
public interface ITest<T> {
    void DoSomething(T parameter);
}

public class Test {
    ITest<T> _test; //error (Type cant be found)

    public Test(Itest<T> _test)
    {
        this._test = test;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Test` class needs to be generic too - otherwise there's no way of knowing what kind of `ITest<T>` the `_test` variable refers to. How would you know how to call `_test.DoSomething()`? The type parameter of `Test` doesn't have to be `T`, of course:

```
public class Test<TFoo> {
    ITest<TFoo> _test;

    public Test(ITest<TFoo> _test)
    {
        this._test = test;
    }
}
```

You'd then construct it as:

```
ITest<string> x = ...;
Test<string> test = new Test<string>(x);
```

Type safety would *stop* you from writing:

```
Test<int> test = new Test<int>(x);
```

because you can't construct a `Test<int>` from an `ITest<string>`.

Alternatively, your `Test` class may only need to take one specific kind of `ITest`, and therefore not be generic at all:

```
public class Test {
    ITest<Guid> _test;

    public Test(ITest<Guid> _test)
    {
        this._test = test;
    }
}
```

It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

EDIT: As noted in comments, if your `Test` class doesn't use any of the aspects of `ITest<T>` which rely on `T`, you might want to create a non-generic base interface:

```
public interface ITest {
    void DoSomethingBland();
}

public interface ITest<T> : ITest {
    void DoSomethingSpecific(T foo);
}
```

Then you could make your class just depend on the non-generic `ITest` interface instead of `ITest<T>`.

Comment: Or a nongeneric `ITest` that `ITest<T>` inherits from.

Comment: great explanation @Jon Skeet, the cause i'm asking this is because i'm creating a new windows forms window, and i'm using generics to inherit from my base class. But when I put my base class to accept generics, i.e FormBase<T> : Form, the designer raises a error, saying 'the base class FormBase<Type> could not be loaded'. I've searched a solution for these error but none of them worked for me :( anyway, great explanation, thanks a lot

Comment: `using generics to inherit from my base class` Can you explain this more? That's not normally what generics are used for as C# supports class inheritance.

Comment: for example: 
I've created a forms like this `FormBase<T> : Form`, to be used as base form. 
In the form that will be really used, I do this: `Sales : FormBase<Model.Sales>`. 
This causing the designer error, when I remove the <T> from the base class the designer is loaded normally.